# How to use "Reference" information from Blender manual?

Tags: interface

There is "Reference" information in many Blender manual pages, for example

[image]

How one can use it? It looks like some path, like in menu, but nothing correspondent can be found in the `GUI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a path in the GUI. Look in the Properties Editor (on the right by default), in the `Scene` tab, under `Gravity`.

[image: Scene > Gravity]

Answer (score 1):

Click the Scene icon on the edge of the right-hand panel and then the little arrow beside the Gravity entry to open the Gravity properties.
Hovering the cursor over the icons will bring up a description for each one.

[image]